# Pull does nothing from Tortoise GUI, command line git works

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am in my local master branch, tracking origin master, with me few commits behind.

When I use TortoiseGit in Explorer ***(TortoiseGit -> Pull (from origin/master, Tags, Prune, AutoLoad Putty Key, Launch Rebase After Fetch***) it looks like content is downloaded from server but when I open log my local/master is still on same SHA, and no new commits are visible in log. Its like rebase didn't happen and I don't see new commits in history unless I switch log to remotes/origin/master.

When I try from cmd: ***git pull --rebase***, everything works as expected and my local branch gets all changes from origin and local/master is on same SHA as origin/master.

How to make Tortoise git work the same as command line git, is this some error or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, pull.  Tortoise git 2.3.0, and Git-2.10.1-64.

Comment: Please re-try with the latest preview release: https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/ (might be related to https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2634)